# How to check when wearable app is installed on watches?

Tags: android, wear-os

I'm trying to figure out when my wearable app is installed on watches to start scheduling local notifications. As everyone knows since Honeycomb package_added intent is not delievered to broadcast receivers. So I need somehow to understand when my app is installed on watches and via "parent" handhandeled app send a message(or put some DataItems) to wake up wearable app. Yes, I can do this on start of main app but this is not what I'm looking for. Are there any broadcasts which can help me or mechanisms to understand that I'm ready to go?

Answer (score 0):

[ACTION_PACKAGE_FIRST_LAUNCH](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_FIRST_LAUNCH) and [ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED) are two Intents you can listen to in your Wearable app which can then send a message to your phone app to kick off the scheduling process (assuming your phone app uses a [WearableListenerService](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/WearableListenerService.html) to receive messages while in the background).

Comment: this makes no sense because : 1) Wearable app was not launched. 2) package was not replaced(first installation). Both apps are in stopped state after installation. Or I'm missing something?